# Comparing substrings in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using SQLite to storage my data. I want to know if there is a way to compare something similar to this:

```
Table Persons
   -----------
      Name      |     "12 34 42"
```

So I want to compare only the substring `34`. Using `LIKE`, wildcards, [`substr(X,Y)`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) and [`instr(X,Y)`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr) always return the row but I don't want that:

```
select * from persons where substr('4', 1) > 0;

select * from persons where instr(name, '4') > 0;
```

Is there a way to only compare a substring in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical way to do this is using `like`:

```
where ' ' || name || ' ' like '% 34 %'
```